# how to print a text to a frame in opencv-python

Tags: python, opencv, raspberry-pi

I am using opencv-python for my face detection experiment. I am also to do a cv.drawRect function. I tried with cv.putText but it is not supported in python.
Is there other functions other than cv.putText which can write text to an image frame

Comment: what did you try so far? and are you using blank opencv or pyopencv?

Comment: i tried using opencv-python.. with import cv2.cv as cv and then when i use cv.puttext it is giving error as package cv does not have attribute puttext

Comment: If you share some code, i can look at it, cv.putText is of course supported

Comment: you should not use the deprecated cv package at all, but cv2 only. (and yes, it has cv2.putText())

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got it. In the older version of python-opencv use PutText instead of putText

```
font = cv.InitFont(cv.CV_FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 1, 1, 0, 3, 8) #Creates a font
x = 10 #position of text
y = 20 #position of text
cv.PutText(image,"Hello World!!!", (x,y),font, 255) #Draw the text
```

Answer (score 1):

In case someone is interested to the new version of opencv-python:

```
import cv2

font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX
color = (255, 0, 0) # red
fontsize = 255
text = "test"
position = (10, 10)

cv2.putText(image, text, position, font, fontsize, color=color)
```

The available default fonts are defined in *modules/imgproc/include/opencv2/imgproc.hpp* header file:

```
enum HersheyFonts {
    FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX        = 0, //!< normal size sans-serif font
    FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN          = 1, //!< small size sans-serif font
    FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX         = 2, //!< normal size sans-serif font (more complex than FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX)
    FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX        = 3, //!< normal size serif font
    FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX        = 4, //!< normal size serif font (more complex than FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX)
    FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL  = 5, //!< smaller version of FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX
    FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX = 6, //!< hand-writing style font
    FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_COMPLEX = 7, //!< more complex variant of FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX
    FONT_ITALIC                 = 16 //!< flag for italic font
};
```

[image: visual font example]

(Image source: [Code Yarns](https://codeyarns.com/tech/2015-03-11-fonts-in-opencv.html))